# Windows 10 Photos (viewer) cannot read .jpg file with ggplot from R script

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg

I used the jpeg driver to export my plots to a directory. The image file gets created but it gives the error message:

`filename.jpg
It appears that we don't support this file format.`

When I tried the pdf option, the file got created but another error message showed:

`The file is already open or in use by another program.`

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

My code:

```
my_path<-"path/my.jpg"
jpeg(file=my_path)
ggplot(data_frame) +
          geom_point(aes(x, y))+
          ggtitle("some name")
dev.off
```

Comment: Does your code use `dev.off` or does it use `dev.off()`. There is a big difference.

Comment: Damn it my bad! Sorry and thanks! Hurried mistake!